# How to get all security groups that are inbound to All traffic to 0.0.0.0

Tags: aws-cli

I'm trying to get all the security groups that are open to "All traffic" from any IP address (0.0.0.0/0) For us, it means they haven't been correctly configured.

I found how to find those that contain a rule that allows SSH traffic (port 22) and a rule that allows traffic from all IP addresses (0.0.0.0/0)
I’ve tried it but I still don't have what I'm looking for : I want those who allows all protocols, all ports(all traffic) from 0.0.0.0.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip
permission.cidr,Values='0.0.0.0/0' Name=vpc-id,Values=XXXXX Name=ip-
permission.from-port,Values=* --query "SecurityGroups[*]. 
{Name:GroupName,ID:GroupId}" --output table
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're on the right track.  If you use a `-1` as the value for `ip-permission.protocol` it will return Security Groups open to all traffic.

I created this Security Group (delete immediately) as a test:

[image]

When I run the `aws` command with the above filter and the filter for CIDR = `0.0.0.0/0` as such:

```
aws ec2 --region eu-west-1 describe-security-groups --filter Name=ip-permission.protocol,Values=-1 Name=ip-permission.cidr,Values='0.0.0.0/0' --query "SecurityGroups[*].{Name:GroupName,ID:GroupId}" --output table
```

It returned this output:

```
------------------------------------------------  
|            DescribeSecurityGroups            |
+-----------------------+----------------------+
|          ID           |        Name          |
+-----------------------+----------------------+
|  sg-0142cbca58aac3836 |  delete immediately  |
+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

**UPDATE**

To list generate a list of security groups that allow all outbound use the following:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filter Name=egress.ip-permission.protocol,Values=-1 Name=egress.ip-permission.cidr,Values='0.0.0.0/0' --query "SecurityGroups[*].{Name:GroupName,ID:GroupId}" --output table
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks! However this query seems to look for `0.0.0.0/0` only in `inbound rules`. Is there a way to search the `outbound rules` as well?

Comment: @Biju I've added an update to the answer.   Thanks for the feedback.